# Why don´t we just do a Legendre transform for a GR hamiltonian?

Tags: general-relativity, constrained-dynamics

In general, if one has a well defined lagrangian for a field theory, which depends on a field, say $A_{\mu}$ and on its first spatial and temporal derivatives, we can simply define the canonical momenta as the functional derivative of the lagrangian with respect to the time derivative of the field, solve the velocities in terms of the momenta, and build a Hamiltonian.

In the Hamiltonian formalism of GR, known as ADM formalism, we don´t follow this straightfoward steps. First, there is a huge amount of geometrical considerations, which is used to define a space-like hypersurface, a extrinsic and intrinsic curvature... then we express the 4 dimensional scalar curvature in terms of geometrical quantities of the hypersurfaces...and only then we can do the legendre transform and define the canonical momenta.

My question is: why don´t we just do a legendre transform from the start to get to the Hamiltonian formalism for gravity, and just follow the same steps we use in other field theories, like electromagnetism? Maybe its because the Einstein-Hilbert action depends on second derivatives of the metric, but we can always go to a first order formalism like Palatini´s, and then we would have a lagrangian which depends on certain fields and its first derivatives, just like EM.

Perhaps the canonical momenta obtained this way would have no physical interpretation, because we did not care to carefully define a foliation, hypersurface, but since all we´re doing is following the steps from the lagrangian to the hamiltonian formulation, the dynamics obtained this way should be identical to the other approachs right? Or not?

Comment: The "Legendre transform" is not as simple as you claim it is. For systems with gauge degrees of freedom (which GR is, due to reparametrization invariance for the coordinates), the transformation is singular, and one incurs constraints since one cannot solve for the momenta in terms of the velocities. Additionally, you need a well defined *Lagrangian* to begin with - and that means you have to integrate the GR Lagrangian density over spatial slices to get the Lagrangian. But that means you first have to define such spatial slices, hence the foliation stuff.

Comment: I know the system will be singular, but that's another story. You can always write the einstein-hilbert lagrangian in a specific coordinate and integrate it in d³x to obtain a Lagrangian L(t). The 3+1 decomposition is about decomposing the 4-curvature in terms of the 3-dimensional geometrical objects + extrinsic curvature. My question still holds: why don't we do a legendre transform directly?